# Горячие клавиши в Android studio

Tags: java, android-studio

Как перейти в родительский класс с помощью горячих
клавиш?

Answer (score 1):

На Хабре есть статья про горячие клавиши. Думаю она вам будет очень полезна:
[Горячие клавиши Android Studio](https://habr.com/post/319562/)